# why receive wrong message in MFC instead of timer message?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a class ClistCtrlEx class that  inherits from ClistCtrl.

I add

- ON_WM_TIMER() to message table
- OnTimer function

but before that call to SetTimer function program recevice WM_TIMER messages by event id 45 and when I call to SetTimer don't send WM_TIMER at all.

how I can start to debug it or fix the problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This KB article seems appropriate: [PRB: OnTimer() Is Not Called Repeatedly for a List Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200054).

Basically, they suggest to only call the default handler if event id is not yours, because the list control sets its own timer and its WM_TIMER handler will `KillTimer()` regardless of the id.

```
void CMyListCtrl::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
   if (nIDEvent == m_myTimerID)
   {
       // handle timer event
   }
   else
   {
      CListCtrl::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
   }
}
```